# Hide BottomNavigationView with a ComposeView in Fragment in Coordinator Layout

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottomnavigationview

I have a view system based BottomNavigationView wrapped inside a CoordinatorView where I am inflating a fragment. This fragment contains a ComposeView with a lazy column. Have set the `HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior` on the BottomNavigationView, still scrolling in Compose Fragment is not hiding the Bottom Nav. It does work with a normal fragment with NestedScrollView parent

Created a Fragment with following code

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
        setContent {
            LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
                items(100){ index ->
                    Text(text = "Index is $index", color = Color.Black)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which when inflated using a bottom nav view, dint work as expected.